# Install HTOP on Wheezy

Tags: raspbian-wheezy

I'm a complete newbie with linux and raspberry.
How can I install htop on wheezy? I know of apt-get, installing rpm with alien. but There is this error and I cant find any relevant info on google. I get what the errors are saying.. but is there another way?

Help?

```
...
warning: rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el5.rf.i386.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 6b8d79e6: NOKEY
rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el5.rf.i386.rpm is for architecture i386 ; the package cannot be built on this system
```

Comment: i figured it out.. sudo apt-get install htop as I said.. I'm new to this.

Answer (score 2):

Just that you know what's wrong with the package you downloaded.

The name of the rpm... especially the part `.i386.` is the cpu architecture the package (rpm, deb, ...) is built for.

Your RPI has ARM archivetecture so you just loaded a rpm for the wrong architecture.

But anyway, installing a package via apt-get is always better than installing an rpm with alien.

Answer (score 0):

You're using Debian, so you'd be better off installing `.deb` and only using `alien` with `.rpm`s if *really* needed.

1. `apt-cache search htop`
2. `sudo apt-get install htop`